# Read excel file function, code freezes ( Python, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

The following line reads a specific excel file from a series of enumerated files, and saves a subset of a column from such a file into a vector. The actual reading is done as a function, so that the vectors corresponding to different Excel files can be compared easily

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def fetch_excel(x):
    df_x = pd.read_excel(f"D00{x}_balance.xlsx")
    return df_x

T = np.zeros(3000)

for i in range(0, 3000):
    T[i] = fetch_excel(1).iloc[i+18, 0]
```

But when I try to do something simple, like print the first element of T the code just freezes and does not execute. I think the problem lies in the for loop. I can call on the function just fine if I comment it out.

Comment: You should use a context manager when reading files. Looks like you're trying to fetch from the same file over and over again, could be your hang point. Also, is the file too big to slurp up all at once, and then work on in-memory?

Comment: What do you mean by slurp? No, I have not looked into opening all the individual Excel files at the same time ( If thats what you meant )